# Implement Server Side Events with Grails

Tags: javascript, html, grails, groovy, server-sent-events

I want to implement Server side events with grails. What i want is that only when there is a change in the DataBase my DataTable should refresh. I want to user HTML5 Server Side events for this. My first question is that while using SSE i observed that the client keeps making a request to the server and if data is available it pulls it. Its similar to an Ajax call being sent every 3-4 seconds which can be changed but what i really want is that only and only when the Data in the DataBase changes should there be a refresh in the DataTable. Also i want to send JSON data to the client but am unable to send it in the right format. Below is my controller code.

```
def test(){

def action
something.each(){

action = "<a href=\"javascript:fetchDetails('"+it.id+"','comments'"+")\" class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-upload'></span></a>"

dataArr << [
                            it.Number,
                            it.product,
                            it.description,
                            OrgChart.findByid(it.Owner)?.displayName,
                            OrgChart.findByid(it.Coordinator)?.displayName,
                            startDate,
                            endDate,
                            it.status.status,
                            action
            ]

    }

    println dataArr

        response.setContentType("text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8")
        response << "data: ${dataArr}\n\n"         
        render "Hi" 
}
}
```

Below is the gsp or the client side code

```
console.log("Starting eventSource");
var eventSource = new EventSource("/ops/test");
console.log("Started eventSource");
eventSource.onmessage   = function(event) {

  var data = JSON.stringify(event.data)

  console.log("Message received: " + JSON.parse(data)); 

  changeRequestsTable.clear().rows.add(JSON.parse(event.data)).draw()

};

eventSource.onopen      = function(event) { console.log("Open " + event); };
eventSource.onerror     = function(event) { console.log("Error " + event); };
console.log("eventState: " + eventSource.readyState);
// Stop trying after 10 seconds of errors
setTimeout(function() {eventSource.close();}, 10000);
```

I know i am a long way from implementing what i intend to but any help would be really appreciated

Comment: take a look at websockets - by consistently checking db for a change through gsp is not really a clever way of doing this

Comment: @vahid : Thanks for the reply ... i went through websockets and from what i grasped was that in websockets there is a 2 way communication that is possible.... i didnt want to go with that approach because all i wanted was that when the server is updated it should push the data to the client ...... but after trying put SSE it seems that the client kind of keeps trying to get data from the server ...... Anyways would like to try it out using SSE as well ..... Or atleast would like to know what exactly am i doing wrong ......

Comment: Web sockets requires each wen page to have a socket connection to a backend listener. The listener can then broadcast to all sessions connected with a response that the pages upon receipt will trigger have script to update page with response content. It can be two way if wen page has functionality to send messages and listener having methods to receive those client requests. Take a look at wschat watch some of the videos

Comment: Your current method has no way of knowing all connected pages so even when you get it working. Multiply your test by 500 concurrent users. Each user having to every few seconds do ajax call to trigger a db search criteria to respond back to each user. This is how bad designs lead to slow applications. You need to use backend events to trigger a call to win sockets possibly telling it to refresh users page. Possibly doing lookup and responding search results once broadcasted to all users. So 1 lookup triggered by event and broadcasted to 500 users with full details to page vs your current way

Comment: @vahid: Interesting point you made ... but in my current application there will be 2 Roles ... Say Requester And Approver ... These two will different views about the same thing which is a Request. So i have 2 different pages using the same javascript file and the same Controller file as well. So what i wanted to achieve is that if the Requester updates a Request it should be shown to the Approver immediately and if an Approver updates the same or different it should be shown to the Requester too immediately ..... Would you still say that this is an incorrect approach to do this

Comment: `immediately` will never be ajax it will always lag behind by sec/ms according to it's lookup. Also it will possibly be looking up consistently and when no need just to ensure there wasn't a need. It is up to you - your application. 2 users battering a db table all day vs idle communication updated when a real update occurs.

Comment: @vahid:Dont get me wrong but just wanted to see what options i have .... i am looking at WebSockets .and i assume that any change i the server would have to be detected by the server side code .... so figuring out how to go about that as well .... ideally i would want that once an update happens it should reflect at both the Requester and Approver end simultaneously ... so yes since its going to be a client server interaction i would have to use WebSockets Thanks for pointing that out by the way .... i figured out why the above code wasnt working i used JSONbuilder and sent the data as JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to answer this since it is getting to be a long conversation. As it stands the solution is too broad to give a proper answer since the angle as to how you do things could vary in such a dramatic range from using `events` that get triggered upon record save that then go off to either make `client socket` connections through application through to `direct socket client connection` at point of save  that triggers something to be sent to clients. These methods are probably all more complex and more entangled and in short can be done all in a much easier way.

1. As the users go their interface get the users to make a ws connection to a backend listener. It can be the same location as in no room/separation (additional complexity needed).

As they join room declare a `static concurrent map` in the top of your websocket [listener that collections each session and userId](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/wschat/WsChatConfService.groovy#L21-L23). I wouldn't do it the chat way since this is injected through a service that keeps it as a collection instead [like this](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugin/queuemail/EmailExecutor.groovy#L26) and changing RunnableFuture to be Websocket sessions like seen in the service link example.

Once you have this you can simply call a [broadcast something like this](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/wschat/messaging/WsChatMessagingService.groovy#L237-L251) that gets hold of your static concurrent map and for each session either broadcasts the entire new list in json and user processes html update with it or sends a trigger to say update page and they go off doing ajax call to update list.

Comment: Thanks for answering my query ... i did do it with SSE and got to know about the problem with its implementation as pointed out by you earlier..... i am now looking into WebSockets .... The problem is i am using Grails 2.2.1..... most of websocket plugins for grails in for versions more than 2.5 .... i did come across atmoshpere plugin for websockets which is supported for the version i am using .... I will play around with it a bit to figure out the best way to implement it ..... Anyways thanks for taking the time out and answering my question

Comment: ye you will need 2.35+ https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/issues/5  for websocket support due to version of tomcat. I was also going to suggest if you are going to have issues with the websocket as obviously highlighted you could still use ajax and introduce ehcache and basically cache the search query. Meaning if the user is hitting a non changed db it should return cache results rather than a new db lookup each ajax call

Answer (score 1):

See the following guide for a tutorial on how to implement Server Sent Events with Grails 3:

http://guides.grails.org/server-sent-events/guide/index.html